# How to display plain HTML of Web Content with Freemarker in Liferay

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

In Liferay Portal 7.2, I have list of elements that are Web Contents. For each Web Content in this list I want to get the HTML result defined in the web content itself.

Having an ADT restricted to one structure with a default template, to list every Web Content it's working for me:

```
<#list entries as entry>                    
        
    <#if hasCategoryId(entry, selectedYearCategoryId) &&
            hasCategoryId(entry, selectedTipoNormativaCategoryId)>
            

        <#assign assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer()/>
        <#assign journalArticle = assetRenderer.getAssetObject()/>

            <@liferay_journal["journal-article"]
                articleId=journalArticle.getArticleId()
                groupId=journalArticle.getGroupId()/>                                    

    </#if>

</#list>
```

"hasCategoryId" is a custom function and this ADT embedded needs to reload the entire page passing the parameteres to itself in the URL.

I was wondering if I want to do it using Ajax and do this stuff in a <strike>MVCRenderCommand</strike> MVCResourceCommand, exists any way to convert a Web Content into HTML giving structureId, articleId, ...

Something like:

```
JournalArticle.getHTML(structureId, templateId);
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, there's the source code to do it. I cannot here give you some refs, but search and found

Comment: If you are doing Ajax calls, you should probably be using MVCResourceCommand, not MVCRenderCommand.

Comment: Let me see if I got that right. You want to get a rendered journal article based on a specific web content template with an Ajax call. Basically, a MVC resource command that receives a journal article ID, web content template ID and returns the HTML of that template with that journal article, is that it?

Comment: That's it, 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this method

```java
    _journalArticleLocalService.getArticleDisplay(
                    themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), articleId, 
                    templateKey, null, themeDisplay.getLanguageId(), 
                    themeDisplay).getContent();
```

you can see more about it on the [docs](https://docs.liferay.com/ce/apps/web-experience/latest/javadocs/com/liferay/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalService.html#getArticleDisplay-long-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.ThemeDisplay-).

As you want to call this code with an Ajax call, you should probably be using MVCResourceCommand. The code would be something like this:

```java
package com.your.packace;

import com.liferay.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.BaseMVCResourceCommand;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCResourceCommand;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.ThemeDisplay;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ContentTypes;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=" + YourPortletKeys.YOUR_PORTLET_NAME,
                "mvc.command.name=/your/command/name"
        },
        service = MVCResourceCommand.class
)
public class GetArticleDisplayMVCResourceCommand extends BaseMVCResourceCommand {

    @Override
    protected void doServeResource(
            ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse)
        throws Exception {

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
                (ThemeDisplay) resourceRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

        String articleId = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "articleId");
        String templateKey = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "templateKey");

        JSONObject response = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

        String html = _journalArticleLocalService.getArticleDisplay(
                themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), articleId,
                templateKey, null, themeDisplay.getLanguageId(),
                themeDisplay).getContent();

        response.put("html", html);

        resourceResponse.setContentType(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON);
        resourceResponse.getWriter().write(response.toString());
    }

    @Reference
    private JournalArticleLocalService _journalArticleLocalService;
}
```

I did not test this code, so let me know if somethig is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, it's exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you're going into Ajax, use the [Headless API](https://help.liferay.com/hc/pt/articles/360028726992-Headless-REST-APIs). You can easily fetch content as JSON or HTML.

Comment: I don't have any trouble with the Ajax call, I'd like to know how to convert a JournalArticle to plain HTML giving an structureId / templateId

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got a bit confused by the references to Ajax and MVCRenderCommand...

Rereading your question I suggest that you simple add a templateKey to your tag invocation, as per https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/apps/web-experience/7.0.11/taglibdocs/liferay-journal/journal-article.html

Something like:

```
<@liferay_journal["journal-article"]
            articleId=journalArticle.getArticleId()
            ddmTemplateKey="654321"
            groupId=journalArticle.getGroupId()/>
```

Comment: I will try to put the full case. Having an ADT embedded in a page and restricted to one structure with a default template. I want to show the list of Web Contents associated with that structure filtered by category. The current solution is to display a dropdown with all the categories having "onchange" -> reload the page with the cageoryId selected as parameter. When this ADT reloads, I use that parameter to filter the enty list to show with FreeMarker.  My question is if it can be done somehow to avoid reloading.